# how I can reset collections.counter in Python?

Tags: python

I want to reset ( count from 0 ) in my list so I need to reset Counter ( count from 0 ) :

```
enter code here

for inread in content.splitlines():
    m=json.loads(inread)
    extracted=m['text'].lower()
    tokenized= nltk.word_tokenize(extracted)
    for word in tokenized:
        nplist=[]
        if my_dict2.get(word) is not None:
            sequence.append(word)
            nplist.append(sequence)
            A = numpy.array(nplist)
            b=Counter(A.flat)
            z=b.most_common(5)
            x.append(z)

sequence[:]
nplist[:]
b.clear()
```

Comment: What's the issue you're getting when you're running the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *could* explicitly set all the values in a `Counter` to zero with the following reassingment:

```
>>> c = Counter('xxxy')
>>> c = Counter({x:0 for x in c})
>>> c
Counter({'y': 0, 'x': 0})
```

... or iterate over the keys and set the values:

```
>>> for x in c:
...     c[x] = 0
```

However, this is not necessary in most cases because the `__getitem__` method of a `Counter` returns zero by default if the key cannot be found, which means that `c[x]` is equivalent to `c.get(x,0)` if `c` is a Counter.

```
>>> c['z']
0
```

In summary: Use the `clear` method:

```
>>> c.clear()
>>> c
Counter()
>>> c['foo']
0
```

Comment: @yadishahryary it's clear, not cleear. In case your used clear, you are probably using it at the wrong point. The method *is* working properly. Use `b.clear()` **inside** of your loop if you want to clear the Counter while looping.

Answer (score 0):

How about just creating a new Counter instance? If that's not desirable for some reason, calling the `clear` method that Counter inherits from `dict` should do the trick.

Comment: how I can create new counter in loop?

Comment: I just read the code and got no idea what you are trying to do. Especially checking for `word ` in `my_dict2` without adding it in the loop. Or creating a numpy array of nplist to iterate over the elements. What are you trying to do?